# Get Value of registry key and Proceed with an IF statement if value = something*

Tags: batch-file

Here is the code that I am using. I am trying to say if the computer name = KH-TC* go to end and exit and if computer name = KH-ZC* run this executable. Any help would be great. Thanks. I dont know scripting at all so im struggling through it. Here is what I have so far:

```
@echo on
REG Query "HKCU\Volatile Environment" /v "ViewClient_Machine_Name"
IF %ErrorLevel% EQU "KH-ZC*" GOTO ZEROCLIENT
IF %ErrorLevel% EQU "KH-TC*" GOTO THINCLIENT

GOTO END
:ZEROCLIENT
@ECHO THIS IS ZERO CLIENT
C:\Windows\System32\tsdiscon.exe
GOTO END

:THINCLIENT
@ECHO THIS IS THIN CLIENT
GOTO END

:END
@ECHO THIS IS END
@exit
```

Comment: What is not working in your script?

Answer (score 2):

Using your code below, it checks for one option and branches on that.
An errorlevel is never a string of characters, always a number.

Here is an answer in just the one command line.
`&&` is a construct that will launch the following command when the errorlevel is 0, from find.exe

```
@echo on
REG Query "HKCU\Volatile Environment" /v "ViewClient_Machine_Name" |find "KH-ZC" >nul && "C:\Windows\System32\tsdiscon.exe"
```

Code using your example below.

```
@echo on
REG Query "HKCU\Volatile Environment" /v "ViewClient_Machine_Name" |find "KH-ZC" >nul

IF %ErrorLevel% EQU 0 (GOTO ZEROCLIENT) else (GOTO THINCLIENT)

:ZEROCLIENT
@ECHO THIS IS ZERO CLIENT
C:\Windows\System32\tsdiscon.exe
GOTO END

:THINCLIENT
@ECHO THIS IS THIN CLIENT
GOTO END

:END
@ECHO THIS IS END
@exit
```

Comment: +1 but I thing `KH-TC*` means that KH-TC must be strictly in the begining.May be FINDSTR?

Comment: @npocmaka You maybe right, we'll have to get confirmation from the OP.  I don't have that registry entry to check it - won't it be in a value though, and not at the start of a line?

Comment: Wow, thank you guys! this is awesome and is almost working now. What would I need to be able to find ZC inside of a registry value string.  For Example (KH-ITZC01) if only looking for ZC? Thank you for all your help!!